# Show Avatar Facebook to ImageView

Tags: android

I used the code as follows to show up facebook avatar to ImageView

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
    img.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+"100002394015528"+"/picture"));
}
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}`
```

But does it not work. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture` doesn't return an image. It returns some response headers including a 302 redirect, and a location header.

Your example for instance redirects to: `http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/211619_100002394015528_568817_q.jpg`

So instead of

```
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

You need to get the headers from the request, follow the location and then do what you were doing before. I don't know Android, or what language that is. (Java?) So I can't help with that, but I think this might be enough information to get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: You can not be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Use this function for get real URL to avatar:

```
 public static String getUrlFacebookUserAvatar(String name_or_idUser )
 {
    String address = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+name_or_idUser+"/picture";
    URL url;
    String newLocation = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false); //Do _not_ follow redirects!
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        newLocation = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newLocation;
}
```